# celestial sphere coordinate system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm prototyping a 3D telescope game that lets you catalog a randomly generated night sky, but I have run into a bit of a wall as I don't know exactly how to represent the objects at the telescope's aim point.

I built a telescope that can slew 360 degrees on the azimuth and 180 degrees of elevation (0 to 90 and down to -90) and within this dome, I suppose I have a finite amount of points from which I could randomly generate some object; such as a star, nebulae, galaxy, pulsar, etc...

But how best to define and model those points?

Would it be as simple as building a list of all the points and filling them objects (or generating them procedurally as they are discovered or analyzed)?

And if so, should I just use azimuth elevation or adopt a coord system more along the lines of Right Ascension and Declination?

Furthermore, I'd want there to be a day/night cycle so adding sidereal time is a concern that I think azimuth/elevation doesn't address.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: To define any co-ordinate system, you will need to define at-least a point of origin, an axis, a reference plane according to which you can use elevation/azimuth angles and distance vector, which will lead you to (R, Theta, and Alpha) co-ordinate system. If you want to add time you can add time in there as well, but origin for time should also be defined, I think that should work fine. You can use a struct to define the co-ordinate system, as it will always have a value and it will never be null.

Comment: This is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic questions for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).